# How do you set the directory in Maya with python? Currently using PyQt4 but open to any suggestions

Tags: python, pyqt4, maya, qtgui, qfiledialog

I need to set the directory in Maya so that when I import a new file it will go to that directory I imported the last file from. It is for multiple scripts. I import files, run a script, then run a new script. I can't use string or reset my project folder. This is the only part of my scripts I can't get to work. Here is a list of my imports:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sip
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import os.path
import maya.mel as mel
```

Here is the part that is giving me trouble (for simplicity I put an actual path). I am new too scripting in general. I know I am missing information, but I have no idea what. I have tired so many different things.

```
#Set file path
directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.setDirectory('C:\Users')
```

I get this error every time:

```
# TypeError: # arguments did not match any overloaded call:
#   QFileDialog.setDirectory(QString): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFileDialog'
 QFileDialog.setDirectory(QDir): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QFileDialog'
```

I have even tried going simple with workspace. It prints correctly with no errors but when I go to file open it takes me back to where I saved last.

```
#Give file path
cmds.workspace(dir='C:\Users')
#Find file path
foo = cmds.workspace(q=True, dir=True)
print foo
```

Here is the script. It is a composite between myself and another person. It's function is to import mesh and auto project UVs. Which are then optimized by the artist. Then exported to save a separate version. The next part is importing the optimize mesh (import is required because the stages need to be able to work independently). I hope this makes more sense now.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import sip
import maya.OpenMayaUI as apiUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import os.path
import maya.mel as mel

class LPUnion(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,
                 parent=getMayaMainWindow(),
                 uniqueHandle='ImportExport'):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Low Poly')
        self.setObjectName(uniqueHandle)
        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):
        """
        Create the class vars and UI elements
        """
        print('setting window')
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        central_widget.setLayout(central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.setGeometry(300,300, 250, 150)

        lbt=QtGui.QLabel("Import low poly for automatic UV mapping")
        self.aBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Import Low Poly")
        self.aBtn.clicked.connect(self.import_low_obj)        

        lbh=QtGui.QLabel("Resize UVs before exporting optimized")
        self.oBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Export Optimized")
        self.oBtn.clicked.connect(self.export_opt_obj) 

        lbn=QtGui.QLabel("Import union for chunking")
        self.uBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Import for Chunking")
        self.uBtn.clicked.connect(self.import_uni_obj)

        lbk=QtGui.QLabel("Export chunking")
        self.yBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Export Chunks")
        self.yBtn.clicked.connect(self.export_chks)

        central_layout.addWidget(lbt)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.aBtn)
        central_layout.addWidget(lbh)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.oBtn)
        central_layout.addWidget(lbn)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.uBtn)
        central_layout.addWidget(lbk)
        central_layout.addWidget(self.yBtn)

        self.show()

#import for optimization
    def import_low_obj(self):
        """
        import a selected file
        """

        lpfiles = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Import for Optimized')
        if lpfiles != None:
            n = str(lpfiles)
            print "name is {0}".format(n)
            #split up name to import other items
            self.root = n.replace(n.split('/')[-1:][0], "")
            print "root is {0}".format(self.root)

            #create new scene
            cmds.file(new=True, force=True)

            # import n
            self.objs = []
            for fn in [n]:
                cmds.file(fn, i=True)
                for o in cmds.ls(type="mesh"):
                    if not o in self.objs:
                        self.objs.append(o)

            #####set directory
            fileName = os.path.dirname(n)
            #####directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.setDirectory('path/to/dir')####

            print self.objs
            cmds.select(cl=True)
            #triangulate mesh
            for o in self.objs:
                cmds.polyTriangulate(o)
            cmds.select(cl=True)

            #automatic mapping of UVs
            cmds.select('mesh', r=True)
            cmds.hilite('mesh', r=True)
            cmds.selectMode(component=True)
            cmds.select('mesh.f[0:10000]', r=True)
            cmds.polyAutoProjection('mesh.f[0:10000]', lm = 1, cm=False, l = 2, sc = 1, o = 1, ps = 0.2, ws=False)



            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None,
                                        "Uploaded",
                                        "Optimize Uvs before exporting.".format(self.intr)) 


#export optimized
    def export_opt_obj(self):
        """
        export the new mesh
        Q:\KITCHEN\mesh\Modo\ECO\113
        """

        #export two copies of obj
        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('mesh')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-lowpoly-optimize", force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")
        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('mesh')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-lowpoly", force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")

        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None,
                                    "Saved",
                                    "Optimized mesh files have been saved.".format(self.intr)) 



#import for chunking
    def import_uni_obj(self):
        """
        import a selected file
        """



        unifiles = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Import for Chunking')


        if unifiles != None:
            n = str(unifiles)
            print "name is {0}".format(n)
            #split up name
            self.root = n.replace(n.split('/')[-1:][0], "")
            print "root is {0}".format(self.root)

            #create new scene
            cmds.file(new=True, force=True)

            # import n
            self.objs = [] #add mesh to this list, LP mesh
            for fn in [n]:
                cmds.file(fn, i=True)
                for o in cmds.ls(type="mesh"):
                    if not o in self.objs:
                        self.objs.append(o)

            print self.objs

            cmds.select(cl=True)
            #triangulate mesh
            cmds.polyTriangulate('mesh')

            #create locator
            cmds.spaceLocator(p = [0, 0, 0])
            cmds.setAttr("locator1.tx", lock=True, channelBox=True)
            cmds.setAttr("locator1.ty", lock=True, channelBox=True)


            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None,
                            "Great!",
                            "From side view move locator to cut position .".format(self.intr))



#export chunking
    def export_chks(self):

        import maya.cmds as cmds

        ###make chunks
        cmds.duplicate('mesh')
        cmds.duplicate('mesh')
        cmds.duplicate('mesh')

        #delete the right side
        leftChunks = ['mesh', 'mesh1']
        for n in leftChunks:
            cmds.select(n)
            cmds.polyCut(cutPlaneCenterX = 0 , cutPlaneRotate = [0, 90, 0], deleteFaces = True)

        #delete the left side
        rightChunks = ['mesh2', 'mesh3']
        for p in rightChunks:
            cmds.select(p)
            cmds.polyCut(cutPlaneCenterX = 0 , cutPlaneRotate = [0, -90, 0], deleteFaces = True)

        #get position of locator
        loPosition = cmds.pointPosition('locator1', w=True)

        #delete front
        backChunks = ['mesh', 'mesh2']
        for f in backChunks:
            cmds.select(f)
            cmds.polyCut(cutPlaneCenter = loPosition, cutPlaneRotate = [180, 0, 0], deleteFaces = True)
        cmds.rename('mesh', 'back_Left')
        cmds.rename('mesh2', 'back_Right')

        #delete back
        frontChunks = ['mesh1', 'mesh3']
        for t in frontChunks:
            cmds.select(t)
            cmds.polyCut(cutPlaneCenter = loPosition, cutPlaneRotate = [0, 0, 0], deleteFaces = True)
        cmds.rename('mesh1', 'front_Left')
        cmds.rename('mesh3', 'front_Right')

        #trianglate chunks
        triMesh = ['back_Left', 'back_Right', 'front_Left', 'front_Right']
        for s in triMesh:
            cmds.select(s)
            cmds.polyTriangulate(s)

        """
        export the new mesh

        """
        #save out chunks
        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('back_Left')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-back-left",force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")

        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('back_Right')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-back-right",force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")

        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('front_Left')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-front-left",force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")

        cmds.select(cl=True)
        cmds.select('front_Right')
        cmds.file(self.root+"mesh-front-right",force=True, es=True, op="groups=1;ptgroups=0;materials=0;smoothing=0;normals=0", typ="OBJexport")


LPUnion()
```

**Here are my references:**

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html

http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/dialogs/

And others.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

This question could be clearer. If you're trying to force a dialog to open in a particular folder, `QFileDialog.setDirectory` is should be called from a QFileDialog object; if you have already created one you can call its setDirectory() method and it should work.

However you can do the same thing with

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.fileDialog2(dir='path/to/dir', dialogStyle=2, fileMode =4)
```

For the fileDialog2 command, see [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/fileDialog2.html)

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer on my question. I went back and included my script. I don't believe I could get the fileDialog2 command to work. Please correct me if I am wrong :)